# Which is the default Python version supported in Ubuntu 15.04 and 15.10?

Tags: 15.04, python, 15.10, default

Which is the default Python version supported in Ubuntu 15.04 and 15.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Ubuntu Package Index, the default version of:

- [Python 2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python) is 2.7.9 for both 15.04 and 15.10.
- [Python 3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3) is 3.4.3 for both 15.04 and 15.10.

Comment: I  just want to only know that default 2.7.x or 3.x is default one in ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: @DaSaDiYaChaiTAnYa Until there's a change to [PEP 0394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/), the `python` command wil start Python 2 on Ubuntu.